# Upload video to my Vimeo account silently (without login screen)

Tags: .net, rest, http

I am trying to upload a video to my pro Vimeo account but I always stumble upon the login screen. I have tried using the unofficial .net api as well as common http requests as described in the Vimeo documentation but I can’t figure it out.

How can I generate an authenticated token by providing my credentials and without the need for a user login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question: You just need to generate an access token from the authorization page in developer.vimeo.com. They never expire so it’s safe.